# Declarations in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, language-lawyer, declaration

From what I have understood, declarations/initializations in C++ are statements with 'base type' followed by a comma separated list of declarators.

Consider the following declarations:

```
int i = 0, *const p = &i; // Legal, the so-called base type is 'int'.
                          // i is an int while p is a const pointer to an int.

int j = 0, const c = 2;   // Error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations.
                          // Intention was to declare j as an int and c an as const int.

int *const p1 = nullptr, i1 = 0; // p1 is a const pointer to an int while i1 is just an int.

int const j1 = 0, c1 = 2;   // Both j1 and c1 are const int.
```

Is `const int` a base type or a compound type?

From the error in the second declaration above, it seems to be a base type. If it is so, then what about the first declaration?

In other words, if the first statement is legal, why isn't the second one? Also, why does the behaviour differ among the third and fourth statements?

Comment: putting several declarations in one line can lead to confusions. Even if you get it right, the next reader might not understand it (next reader might be you after some months). Imho best practice is to declare one variable per line. But dont get me wrong, of course it is good to understand how it works

Comment: There is no such thing as a base type in C++.   `int` is a type while `const`, `*`, and `&` are examples of type qualifiers.    Declarations use types and (optionally) type qualifiers to create identifiers.

Comment: @Peter There is no "type qualifier" in C++ either. `const` is a cv-qualifier (and it can be both a declarator and a specifier), while `*` and `&` are declarators.

Comment: @tobi303: I don't see any problem with several variables declared in one line... as long as all have the same type. When you start mixing types, I polish my chainsaw.

Comment: That's a hell of a question for a beginner! Welcome to C++, and I'll be looking forward to your contributions in the future.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree to some extend. As soon as a pointer is involved I always go for one variable per line, because `int *i,*j;` looks just stupid imho while `int* i,j` can be misleading

Comment: @tobi303: Oh yes, given the oddity of declarators, pointers or references should be isolated, always!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Good question, with a complicated answer. To really grasp this, you need to understand the internal structure of C++ declarations quite thoroughly.

(Note that in this answer, I will totally omit the existence of attributes to prevent overcomplication).

A declaration has two components: a sequence of *specifiers,* followed by a comma-separated list of *init-declarators*.

Specifiers are things like:

- storage class specifiers (e.g. `static`, `extern`)
- function specifiers (e.g. `virtual`, `inline`)
- `friend`, `typedef`, `constexpr`
- **type specifiers**, which include:

  - simple type specifiers (e.g. `int`, `short`)
  - **cv-qualifiers** (`const`, `volatile`)
  - other things (e.g. `decltype`)

The second part of a declaration are the comma-separated init-declarators. Each init-declarator consists of a sequence of *declarators,* optionally followed by an *initialiser.*

What declarators are:

- identifier (e.g. the `i` in `int i;`)
- pointer-like operators (`*`, `&`, `&&`, pointer-to-member syntax)
- function parameter syntax (e.g. `(int, char)`)
- array syntax (e.g. `[2][3]`)
- **cv-qualifiers**, if these follow a pointer declarator.

Notice that the declaration's structure is strict: first specifiers, then init-declarators (each being declarators optionally followed by an initialiser).

The rule is: specifiers apply to the entire declaration, while declarators apply only to the one init-declarator (to the one element of the comma-separated list).

Also notice above that a cv-qualifier can be used as both a specifier and a declarator. As a declarator, the grammar restricts them to only be used in the presence of pointers.

So, to handle the four declarations you have posted:

## 1

```
int i = 0, *const p = &i;
```

The specifier part contains just one specifier: `int`. That is the part that all declarators will apply to.

There are two init-declarators: `i = 0` and `* const p = &i`.

The first one has one declarator, `i`, and an initialiser `= 0`. Since there is no type-modifying declarator, the type of `i` is given by the specifiers, `int` in this case.

The second init-declarator has three declarators: `*`, `const`, and `p`. And an initialiser, `= &i`.

The declarators `*` and `const` modify the base type to mean "constant pointer to the base type." The base type, given by specifiers, is `int`, to the type of `p` will be "constant pointer to `int`."

## 2

```
int j = 0, const c = 2;
```

Again, one specifier: `int`, and two init-declarators: `j = 0` and `const c = 2`.

For the second init-declarator, the declarators are `const` and `c`. As I mentioned, the grammar only allows cv-qualifiers as declarators if there is a pointer involved. That is not the case here, hence the error.

## 3

```
int *const p1 = nullptr, i1 = 0;
```

One specifier: `int`, two init-declarators: `* const p1 = nullptr` and `i1 = 0`.

For the first init-declarator, the declarators are: `*`, `const`, and `p1`. We already dealt with such an init-declarator (the second one in case **1**). It adds the "constant pointer to base type" to the specifier-defined base type (which is still `int`).

For the second init-declarator `i1 = 0`, it's obvious. No type modifications, use the specifier(s) as-is. So `i1` becomes an `int`.

## 4

```
int const j1 = 0, c1 = 2;
```

Here, we have a fundamentally different situation from the preceding three. We have two specifiers: `int` and `const`. And then two init-declarators, `j1 = 0` and `c1 = 2`.

None of these init-declarators have any type-modifying declarators in them, so they both use the type from the specifiers, which is `const int`.

Comment: So it is basically an explicit exception.

Comment: @Angew What can be the logic behind allowing cv-qualifiers only with pointers and not otherwise? Can you think of an example where such a restriction will be justified?

Answer (score 7):

This is specified in [dcl.dcl] and [dcl.decl] as part of the `simple-declaration`* and boils down to differences between the branches in `ptr-declarator`:

```
declaration-seq:
    declaration

declaration:
    block-declaration

block-declaration:
    simple-declaration

simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seqopt init-declarator-listopt ;
----

decl-specifier-seq:
    decl-specifier decl-specifier-seq    

decl-specifier:    
    type-specifier                               ← mentioned in your error

type-specifier:
    trailing-type-specifier

trailing-type-specifier:
    simple-type-specifier
    cv-qualifier
----

init-declarator-list:
   init-declarator
   init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
   declarator initializeropt

declarator:
    ptr-declarator

ptr-declarator:                                 ← here is the "switch"
    noptr-declarator
    ptr-operator ptr-declarator

ptr-operator:                                   ← allows const
    *  cv-qualifier-seq opt

cv-qualifier:
    const
    volatile

noptr-declarator:                               ← does not allow const
    declarator-id

declarator-id:
    id-expression
```

The important fork in the rules is in `ptr-declarator`:

```
ptr-declarator:
    noptr-declarator
    ptr-operator ptr-declarator
```

Essentially, `noptr-declarator` in your context is an `id-expression` only. It may not contain any `cv-qualifier`, but qualified or unqualified ids. However, a `ptr-operator` may contain a `cv-qualifier`.

This indicates that your first statement is perfectly valid, since your second `init-declarator`

```
 *const p = &i;
```

is a `ptr-declarator` of form `ptr-operator ptr-declarator` with `ptr-operator` being `* const` in this case and `ptr-declarator` being a unqualified identifier.

Your second statement isn't legal because it is not a valid `ptr-operator`:

```
 const c = 2
```

A `ptr-operator` must start with `*`, `&`, `&&` or a nested name specifier followed by `*`. Since `const c` does not start with either of those tokens, we consider `const c` as `noptr-declarator`, which does not allow `const` here.

> Also, why the behaviour differs among 3rd and 4th statements?

Because `int` is the `type-specifier`, and the `*` is part of the `init-declarator`,

```
*const p1
```

declares a constant pointer.

However, in `int const`, we have a `decl-specifier-seq` of two `decl-specifier`, `int` (a `simple-type-specifier`) and `const` (a `cv-qualifier`), see `trailing-type-specifier`. Therefore both form one declaration specifier.

---

<sub>* Note: I've omitted all alternatives which cannot be applied here and simplified some rules. Refer to section 7 "Declarations" and section 8 "Declarators" of C++11 ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)) for more information.</sub>